# How to (de)serialize POJO to Avro and Kafka without generating code

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, jackson, avro

I want to serialize a POJO to Kafka using Avro but I do not want to generate the POJO. There are several reason that I do not want to use generated code.

1. I want to have control about the POJO structure. I want to use inheritance, I want to add methods, I want to use Kotlin data classes
2. Avro generated code has some issues like [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jackson Kafka Avro serializer](https://github.com/productboardlabs/jackson-kafka-avro-serializer) which does exactly that. It (de)serializes the data using Jackson so you can easily map the POJOs to Avro schemas and back. Moreover, it has first class Kotlin support.